# Using the newly created primary key in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL

in my table I have the column "id" that is an auto incremented primary key. When I create a new row, I would like to use that newly created primary key value in another column of the new row. How would I do so?

[image]

Comment: what RDBMS product you are using. plz, specify the version as well. if it is SQL server you can use a computed column(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: my bad, i'm using postgresql

Comment: You can use triggers as explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/set-a-columns-default-value-to-the-concatenation-of-two-other-columns-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a trigger for this:

```
create or replace function t_update_message_id_trigger()
returns trigger as
$body$
begin
    new.message_id := new.id;
    return new;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_update_message_id before insert on t
    for each row execute procedure t_update_message_id_trigger();
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e79243ace266cd7fc034d20b81f93a6e) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating how it works.

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated!!